# Git commit squashing (rebase -i): how do commits actually work?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I don't quite understand how the commits are squashed with git rebase -i. There is one thing I was left wondering:

If my rebase -i produces this list:

```
pick A Last commit

pick B Commit

pick C Some other commit
```

Should I squash commits A and B or B and C? Problem is git said in this case that it would rebase D..A onto D (D being the last commit before this) rather than C..A onto C which would make sense to me. D is not shown at all, so why word it like that?

Comment: Not sure why you're asking us if you should squash A and B or B and C - squash the two that you want to squash!

Comment: What I meant is, which way does this work? What if I leave two picks and mark the one in between as a squash, where are those changes squashed?

Comment: A commit will be squashed into the previous one - the one above it in the list. (By the way, I'm not sure why you have your list in the reverse order...)

Comment: @Jefromi: By accident... but thank's, that's what I wanted to make sure of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that `D..A` in git terminology means "from D to A not including D itself".  If you look into `git-rev-list` manual page, you'll see that

> notation "`<commit1>..<commit2>`" can be used as a short-hand for "`^<commit1> <commit2>`"

which means "list all commits that are *included* in `<commit2>`, but are not included in `<commit1>`.  And **the changes made by `D` itself are included in `D` commit**.  So it's not included in list denoted as `D..A`.

That's why it's correct to say that `git rebase -i D` affects `D..HEAD`.